# Proper use of Angular service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-services

I am currently designing a store management system, just simple take in and take out of store items, at this point I have a service in my AngularJS app which loads all of the items available, which looks something like this:

```
storeApp.service("partsService", function ($http, $q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('loadStoreItems.php').then( function (data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    });

    this.getParts = function () {
        return deferred.promise;
    };
});
```

Now I need to implement a function which given a specific part number entered by the user name, returns the specific item with that part number so I can store it in another array of parts that the user has taken.

I know the logic is easy enough, and I could easily implement this in the controller, but my (limited) understanding is that logic in the controller should be avoided, so I'm thinking this should be implemented as a service.

I'm trying to understand how I would go about doing this, I've been doing some research, but still feel lost. Where should I start?

Comment: A service is useful for re-using logic. Logic in your controller isn't an issue

Answer (score 0):

Angular services are:

Lazily instantiated – Angular only instantiates a service when an application component depends on it.
Singletons – Each component dependent on a service gets a reference to the single instance generated by the service factory.

It might help you!!!

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

    app.service('getDemoService', function($http) {
      this.getDemoResult = function() {
        return $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: baseURL + 'Api/AccountPref/Get/' + uid
        });
      };
    });

    app.controller("MyDemoController", function($scope, getDemoService) {
      $scope.resultData = [];

      getDemoService.getDemoResult().then(function(data) {
        var items = data.items;
       //TODO: here your logic
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use another method of partsService. for example:

```
this.getPartsByNumber = function(partNumber){
    return $http.get('loadStoreItems.php?partNumber=' + partNumber)
}
```

and in controller you can use

```
partsService.getPartsByNumber(123).then(function(response){ 
    $scope.parts = response.data 
})
```